# How do you get a particle to spawn near a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to implement a "sweating" effect and when I try to run the command instead of the particle spawning at the player it spawns at the Command Block

here is what I have tried...

```
/particle dripWater ~ ~1 ~ 0.2 0.25 0.15 12 1 @a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a command block that makes the player execute the command.

Syntax:

```
/execute <x> <y> <z> detect <x2> <y2> <z2> <block> <data> <command …>
/execute <entity> <command …>
```

So, you could try making the player execute the sweating instead.
Presume your player has a score that deduces his temperature (call it `temperature`), and we want him to sweat if it's above `35`.

Run this command on a loop:

```
/execute @a[score_temperature_min=35] particle dripWater ~ ~1 ~ 0.2 0.25 0.15 12 1 @p
```

Comment: Or omit the part `[score_temperature_min=35]` for nonstop sweating.